# Ionic 2 camera error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, camera

So I'm building an app in Ionic 2 and I have a function to access the camera, but for some reason it's not working and the function doesn't even execute properly. 
Below are the relevant HTML and JS files, as well as screenshots of the console log. Any help is very much appreciated!

**app.html**

```
    <ion-menu [content]="content">

    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item *ngFor="#p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
                {{p.title}}
            </button>
                <ion-slides style="height: 50vh">
                    <ion-slide *ngFor="#image of images">
                        <ion-card>
                            <img [src]="image.src"/>
                        </ion-card>
                    </ion-slide>
                </ion-slides>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<button fab primary fab-bottom fab-center (click)=takePicture() style="z-index: 999">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
</button>
<script src="camera.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**camera.js**

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {Camera} from 'ionic-native';
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/app/app.html'
})
    export class HomePage {
    public base64Image: string;
    constructor() {
    }
    takePicture(){
        console.log('click');
        Camera.getPicture({
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            targetWidth: 1000,
            targetHeight: 1000
        }).then((imageData) => {
            // imageData is a base64 encoded string
            this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

**console**
[image]

[image]

Comment: according to errror mention your function named takePicture not found. please check the corspondense .ts/.js file for the function

Comment: I attached that JS file in the post.

Answer (score 3):

takePicture should be in quotes...

`(click)="takePicture()"`